# Difference between BEGIN ATOMIC and BEGIN

Tags: sql, db2

A question regardning SQL DB2 engine. 
What is the difference between

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
 ...code
END
```

And

```
BEGIN
  ..code
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be easiliy found in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=s-compound-sql-compiled):

> **ATOMIC** or **NOT ATOMIC**
>
> ATOMIC indicates that if an unhandled exception condition occurs in the compound statement, all SQL statements in the compound statement will be rolled back.
>
> NOT ATOMIC indicates that an unhandled exception condition within the compound statement does not cause the compound statement to be rolled back.

Comment: Thank you for your simple to understand answer.